# Вызов функции через определённое время

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть код:

```
   $(document).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault;
            if (e.which === 1) {
                createBullet();
                playrandom();
            }
                else {
                       createtbullet();
                       createtbullet();
                       createtbullet();
                       plsn();
        });
```

Как сделать так, чтобы в `else{...}` между вызовом функций `createbullet()` проходило 100 мс?

Comment: [setTimeout][1]


  [1]: http://javascript.ru/setTimeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTimeout(createtbullet(), 0);
setTimeout(createtbullet(), 100);
setTimeout(createtbullet(), 200);
setTimeout(plsn(), 200);
```

Как вам такая реализация?

Comment: Спасибо, подошло.

Answer (score 0):

Или как советовал [[@Alex18](/users/5493/alex18)](/users/5493/alex18), или setInterval(). Всё зависит от поставленной задачи. Пример с setInterval: [бесконечный цикл](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/BHs6C/) и [ограниченное количество](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/BHs6C/1/) выполнения.